# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geoCountry' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

In my **magento** one page checkout module throw error of jquery below error message.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '**geoCountry**' of null from **checkout.js**

Website url is http://ffoa.com.au/

Comment: Maybe you should add a null check...

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question but I just stumbled into the same problem, I used the mt-divas theme which uses also /iwd/opc/checkout.js like your site.

The Error "Cannot read property 'geoCountry' of null" appeared when the user was not logged and checkout as guest is not allowed. In this case when you trying to go to checkout without being logged in you'll see the loggin form on the /onestepcheckout site. The opc.js is loaded but can't access some data.

solution remove the js from the site when user is not logged in:

```
<customer_logged_out>
<reference name="head">
<!-- For a JS in the js folder -->
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>iwd/opc/checkout.js</name>       </action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>iwd/opc/extend.js</name>    </action>
</reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

in iwd_opc.xml or local.xml